# Create fileobj/filter from procedure + data-target vs. data-source

Tags: postscript

I'm playing around with filters and file objects and have two questions to the PostScript gurus:

1. I want to use a procedure which produces a lot of strings as data source for a filter. However, I can only get the last string on the stack to be accepted/processed by the filter:

   `GS>/source {(str1) (str2)} def`
   `GS>/fileobj {source /ReusableStreamDecode filter} def`
   `GS>fileobj dup bytesavailable string readstring {==} if`
   `(str2)`

   String concatenation is not an option because of the 65k limit. Instead I'd like to have a file object which contains all strings from the procedure. Is this possible?

   The PLRM says: *"The data source or target can be a procedure. When the filter file is read or written, it calls the procedure to obtain input data to be decoded or to dispose of output data that have been encoded. This enables the data to be supplied or consumed by an arbitrary program."*

   Any help to get this actually done appreciated.
2. Is it possible to change a file object from a data target to a data source? One could write strings to a `(w) file` on the filesystem and then read them from that `(r) file`. However maybe there is a way without being depended on the PostScript interpreters capability to access the file system? So, I'd be interested in a "gender changer" for file object which accepts strings to be written into and later strings to be read from (while staying a file object, not an array of strings etc.). Is this possible? Haven't found any info in the PLRM. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK there's a mis-understanding of the way that the procedure data source works. It doesn't return a number of strings, it returns a single string each time it is called. If the string is generated procedurally, then it is a different string each time. In your case, its always the last string, as you've discovered because your procedure doesn't change the strings. There's no magic in the interpreter, it doesn't know you've returned 'n' strings, it only ever expects one.

Example:

```
/Index 0 def
/StringArray [(string1) (string2)] def
/ProcSource {
  StringArray Index get 
  Index 1 add
  dup 1 gt {
    pop /index 0 def
  } {
    /Index exch def
  }ifelse
} bind def
```

NB I haven't actually tried that code out, but hopefully you see what I mean.

Some other observations:

The 64Kb limit is not a language limit, its an implementation limit of Adobe interpreters. Many interpreters (including Ghostscript) don't have that limitation. So if you're working solely with Ghostscript you don't need to worry about it.

You can always close a file and reopen it if you want to change between read and write.

Ghostscript, like most level 3 PostScript interpreters, has a RAM file system (%ram% IIRC) and you can place files there (subject to available memory) if you don't want to use the host OS file system.

I don't really understand what problem you're trying to solve, perhaps if you could explain that, I might be able to make some suggestions.

By the way, the Ghostscript ReusableStreamDecode filter works by reading all the data from the underlying source and storing it in a single string (it may switch to a file at some point, I don't remember the details)

Comment: Ken, thanks for the clarification on how procedure data sources work.

Unfortunately my requirement is running the code on a PS3 printer which sticks to the 64Kb limit for strings and does not allow to create named files or access to the `%ram%` file system (even though the PS 3010 and 3011 supplement says _"%ram% is required on all version 3010 products"_). That's why I'd like to use file objects instead of named files. But as it seems, it is **impossible** (?) to write multiple strings to a single file object (and eventually also reading them from that file object again). :(

Comment: Well its not impossible as long as you actually have a file, on a file system. If your printer has neither a ram nor disk file system, then yes its obviously impossible too read and write to the file system, because there isn't one..... A file object is just a PostScript representation of a 'named file', the same as a FILE * in C. So implement your own, store the strings in an array. That allows you 64K strings each of which can be 64K in size. You can concatenate strings less than 64K if you want to keep the number of elements down. Note that this is limited by available memory.